# How do you access a single property in an array of objects in Angular 6 typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently making a budget app. I have an array of expenses that I can add to with a price property. It is constructed off a expense.model.ts. I am trying to access the price property within Typescript. I can already access it on HTML with the ngFor loop. Is there a way to do it within TypeScript with a for loop?

expenses.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Expense } from '../expenses-list/expense/expense.model';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ExpensesService {
  expenses: Expense [] = [
    new Expense('car payment', 350) // price
];
constructor() { }
onAddExpenseToExpenses(expense: Expense) {
  this.expenses.push(expense);
}

// EXAMPLE //
onCalculate() {
  // get prices from listed items
  // add all the prices
  // subtract income from sum of prices
}
```

Sorry if I am not that clear. I just started using Angular 6.

Thanks for your help! =)

Here is my expense model

```
export class Expense {
  private item: string;
  private price: number;

constructor(item: string, price: number) {
    this.item = item;
    this.price = price;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we have more information about the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use for loop in typescript

define expenses like this

```
expenses: Array<Expense>
```

and in constructor please write code below

```
this.expenses = new Array<Expense>()
let x = new Expense('car payment', 350);
this.expenses.add(x);
//or
this.expenses.push(x);
```

after that in onCalculate write this

```
let sum = 0
for (let item of expenses) {
   sum += item.Price;
}
```

for more information about Loop study [Iterators and Generators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html) on typescriptlang website

Comment: I have tried that already. I get an error telling me to use const instead of let within the for loop

Comment: I changed that code However, your problem has been resolved. it’s my pleasure

Comment: Awesome! It worked. It was because it was not letting me access the price property since it was private. Switching it to your way and removing the private variables allowed me to access it. Thanks again!

Comment: it’s my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript and JavaScript are almost the same without Type and Interface. You should learn and reference JS docs

There are many ways to do with loop:

For:

```js
  let sumPrices = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < this.expenses; i++) {
    sumPrices += this.expenses[i].price;
  }
```

For ... of:

```js
  let sumPrices = 0;
  for (const o of this.expenses) {
    sumPrices += o.price;
  }
```

Array map:

```js
  // get prices from listed items
  // add all the prices
  const sumPrices = this.expenses.reduce((acc, o) => acc + o.price, 0);
```